# Create a PDF of the unhidden sheets Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a simple emailing script for a google sheet. I need it to attach the PDF of the active file, but only 3 sheets (the 3 unhidden sheets). I have tried several things but nothing seems to work, I am honestly not an expert in Google script so I may be missing something obvious. Following is my code:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Email');
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = row[2];
    var file= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{cc:"example@gmail.com",attachments:[file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
  }
}
```

What it does is attach the whole spreadsheet as a PDF, which doesn't help me because there are a lot of hidden sheets that I don't need in the PDF. Please help me!! Thanks!

Comment: If the sheets are hidden they won't show up in the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will send emails to recipient in the Emails Sheet which also contains the subject and the message.  It also creates a PDF of the current Spreadsheet with the sheets that are in the incl array.  After the email is sent it returns the sheets back to their original visibility state.

```
function emailAsPDF() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var incl=['Sheet2','Emails'];
  var pdfFolderId="Folder Id";
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFolderId);
  var sObj={shA:[]};
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(sh,i){
    sObj.shA.push(sh.getName());
    if(sh.isSheetHidden()) {
      sObj[sh.getName()]='hide';
    }else{
      sObj[sh.getName()]='show';
    }
    if(incl.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1) {
      sh.showSheet();
    }else{
      sh.hideSheet();
    }
  });
  var file=folder.createFile(ss.getBlob()).setName(ss.getName()).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Emails');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){if(e){hObj[e]=i;}})
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    var recipient=r[hObj.recipient];
    var subject=r[hObj.subject];
    var message=r[hObj.message];
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message, {attachments:[file]})
  })
  sObj.shA.forEach(function(name,i){
    if(sObj[name]=='hide') {
      ss.getSheetByName(name).hideSheet();
    }else{
      ss.getSheetByName(name).showSheet();
    }
  });
}
```

This is an image of my Emails sheet:

[image]

I know...It's pretty trivial but you can improve it as you wish.

Comment: Hey Cooper, thank you this is awesome, I was able to use your code to complete mine and it works perfectly.